# Measure that indicates sales volume per product per day (Google Data Studio)

Tags: looker-studio

I need to implement a measure that indicates sales volume per product per day. For the example table below (each line is a record of a sale):

```
id,create_date,report_date,quantity
329,2019-01-02 08:19:17,2019-01-02 14:34:12,6
243,2019-01-02 09:11:42,2019-01-03 15:30:14,6
238,2019-02-02 08:19:17,2019-03-02 14:36:17,2
170,2019-04-02 02:15:17,2019-04-02 14:37:12,2
238,2019-04-02 08:43:11,2019-04-02 14:41:01,8
238,2019-04-02 08:52:52,2019-04-02 14:39:12,1
238,2019-08-02 08:10:09,2019-08-02 15:02:12,1
238,2019-10-02 08:10:17,2019-10-02 18:34:11,1
170,2020-01-02 08:24:14,2020-01-02 19:31:31,2
170,2020-01-02 08:32:16,2020-01-02 21:52:32,3
```

The operations to reach the result:

**1. Identify total sales and total products for each day.**

For 2019-01-02, two sales were carried out, totaling 12 products (6 products for each sale on the day)

**2. Divide total products by total sales, resulting in the product/sale ratio for the day (if the result is 2, it indicates that each sale on average corresponds to two products).**

In the example table there are 6 different dates (YYYMMDD), for each corresponding date: total products/amount of sales on the day (12/2, 2/1, 11/3, 1/1, 1/1, 5/1) .

**3. Average every day's story, resulting in a single value.**

(3 + 2 + 3.6 + 1 + 1 + 3)/6 = 2.26 , indicating that on average two products are sold per sale per day.

As it involves many operations, I couldn't get a solution for this problem. If anyone can help me.

note: I accept alternative suggestions to offer the measure to indicate the volume of sales per product per day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the numbers given in your steps 2 and 3:

- 12/2=6 not 3
- 5/1 must be 5/2

I still think that you want to calculate a 'day story' in step 2, see formular below.

Here are the steps for generating such a value:

- create a table
- add your time as dimension and make it to date not date&time
- order by date ascending (optional)
- create a field `day story` with the formula `sum(quantity)/count(id)`
- add this field three times to your table
- click on the `AUT` left to the fieldname and select Running calculation to 'running average`

[image]

[image]

You have to convince your users to only look at the last line of the table.

Comment: Your answer was very helpful, getting the result. The only problem is that the visualization format is in a table, in case there are thousands of records it is not advantageous for the user to go through the table to get the correct result. In addition to the desired value being present only in the last line of the last column, and all other information just polluting the screen.

But thanks for the help, it helped open new horizons.